# Table View Footer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, footer

I'm trying to create a footer in a table view using Swift. A single footer that's always at the bottom of the screen. I set up a .swift file called TableViewFooter.swift that creates a class called TableViewFooter, a subclass of UITableViewHeaderFooterView. TableViewFooter has 2 labels, a button, and a progress view. In my TableViewController I put the code:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "TableViewFooter", bundle: nil)
tableView.registerNib(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "TableViewFooter")

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection     section: Int) -> UIView? {
let currSection = fetchedResultsController.sections?[section]
let title = currSection!.name

let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("TableViewFooter")
let header = cell as! TableViewFooter
header.titleLabel.text = title

return cell
}
```

I'm getting an "Expected declaration" error after the tableView.registerNib line, a "Use of unresolved identifier 'fetchedResultsController'" error after the let currSection line, and a "Use of unresolved identifier 'header'" error after the header.titleLabel.text line. I'm new at this, but I'm using a Swift file, not a nib, so shouldn't I be putting something else instead? The only tutorials I found are using nibs or the cryptic Apple reference. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "A single footer that's always at the bottom of the screen." That would not be a table view footer. The table view footer scrolls with the table rows. If you want something that is "always at the bottom of the screen", put it _below_ the table view.

Comment: Ah, ok. So set up a regular view controller that contains the 2 labels, a button, and a progress view and segues into my table view controller?

Comment: Or maybe as a container view with the table view as a child within it?

Comment: A custom parent view controller with a table view controller as its child is the standard way to get the benefits of a table view controller while including other interface besides the table view. On the other hand, the "benefits of a table view controller" are not very great; no law says you can't have labels, button, and table view all governed by a _normal_ view controller.

Comment: Ok, great, thanks matt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want one of two things:

A UITableView footer. This is a view at the bottom of your UIScrollView, meaning that it only shows when you scroll to the bottom of the table. You can modify this, by accessing the tableViewFooter property of your UITableView, in your view controller, which I assume is your delegate and dataSource.

Or, a view that always remains at the bottom of your screen. This is not a table view footer, but a view that you will add to the main view of your view controller. To do this, add a custom UIView at the bottom of your view, making sure that it does not overlap with your table view (otherwise, the user won't be able to get to the bottom cell), and make sure that the scrollView property of your table view is large enough to contain all of its cells.

Comment: Yep, I want the second one. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Getting a view like that, without overlapping your tableView, can be tricky. I'd close this issue, give it a shot, and come back when you hit your next wall, and can ask a more specific question. Good luck!