# How do I had a footer to my static UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, footer

I have a settings screen and I want to add a footer in my *static* `UITableView` that contains the app's version number:

[image]

I've read many posts on SO and the vast majority of them seem to be Objective-C and/or adding a footer in a `UITableView` with dynamic content using `tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)` and others. I found an answer to [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075939/table-view-footer-in-swift) that suggests simply using the `UITableView.tableFooterView` property so I've tried this as well and still get nothing as seen in the image above.

Here's what I've done:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setUpView()
  }

  func setUpView() {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Settings"

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissSettings(_:)))

    formulasTitle.textColor = UIColor.black
    liftsTitle.textColor = UIColor.black
    roundNumbersTitle.textColor = UIColor.black
    sendFeedbackTitle.textColor = UIColor.black
    unitsTitle.textColor = UIColor.black
    pleaseRateTitle.textColor = UIColor.black
    legalMumboJumboTitle.textColor = UIColor.black

    currentFormulaSelection.detailTextLabel!.text = settingsViewModel.defaultFormulaName
    currentLiftsSelection.detailTextLabel!.text = settingsViewModel.defaultLiftName
    weightUnitControl.selectedSegmentIndex = settingsViewModel.weightUnitSelectedSegmentIndex
    roundNumbersSwitch.isOn = settingsViewModel.roundNumbersSwitchOn

    roundNumbersSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.roundingOptionDidChange), for: .valueChanged)
    weightUnitControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(weightUnitDidChange), for: .valueChanged)

    let versionLabel = UILabel()
    versionLabel.text = getVersion()
    let footer = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()

    tableView.tableFooterView = footer

  }

  func getVersion() -> String {
    let appVersion = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") ?? "0"
    let appBuild = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleVersion") ?? "0"

    let versionLabelText: String
    versionLabelText = "Version \(appVersion) (\(appBuild))"

    return versionLabelText
   }
```

Is using `tableView.tableFooterView` the correct solution and I'm just doing it incorrectly or do I add a footer some other way?

**EDIT #1**

I've added this based on Taras's answer but still, nothing:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let versionLabel = UILabel()
    versionLabel.text = getVersion()

    let footer = UITableViewHeaderFooterView(reuseIdentifier: "footer")
    tableView.tableFooterView = footer
    tableView.register(UITableViewHeaderFooterView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "footer")
    footer.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100)
    footer.contentView.addSubview(versionLabel)
    footer.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    footer.constrainToSuperView()
  }

extension UIView {
  func constrainToSuperView() {
    guard let superview = superview else {
      return
    }
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor).isActive = true
    bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
  }
}
```

Two strange things to note: At runtime, the frame of `footer` is `(50.0, 535.333333333333, 375.0, 100.0)`. Also, if I do this, I see the label with the version number but it's aligned left and I can't seem to center it:

```
 footer.textLabel?.text = versionLabel.text
```

Comment: By calling it a "static" table are you saying it has no delegate? You've posted no delegate code - and if you have a delegate, it's a simple matter of using the correct override.

Comment: By "static" I just mean that I'm not using prototype cells and the number of cells in the table view will never change. The only delegate function I've implemented is `tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath)
` to figure out which segue to use when a selection is made.

Comment: Agreed, @dtd. I'm still not getting something, but I'm very close. I've updated my edit to add the `heightForFooterInSection` method that I did implement but forgot to include in my update. I also removed the frame on `footerView` as you suggested and the footer view still looks good. The only problem is that the `UILabel` doesn't appear.

Comment: Thanks to the two thoughtful people who down voted my question. I see hundreds of questions on SO that break every question asking rule there is - they post no code, are unclear, haven't tried anything to solve the problem themselves, and sometimes consist only of a single sentence like, "How to create UITableView?" - and they don't get any down votes. Yet I've spent hours and hours researching my problem, I ask this very reasonable question, I'm careful to try and include relevant code and I get two down votes with zero explanation as to why. Thanks guys, really, thank you. You're SO heroes.

Comment: I knew it wasn't you, @dfd - you were being helpful. I was tracking you on your earlier suggestion so I explicitly set the frame on `footer` as you can see in my edit. However, at runtime when I print the frames of `footer` and `versionLabel` I get `Footer frame is (50.0, 535.333333333333, 375.0, 100.0)` and `Label frame is (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`. I don't understand how the footer frame values are changing like that. Also, I'm using a storyboard and Auto Layout for the rest of this VC, but I'm doing this view in code to learn more about how this stuff works.

Answer (score 2):

```
let footer = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()

tableView.tableFooterView = footer
```

in this two lines you created empty footer with zero frame. Try to use next:

```
let footer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: UIScreen.main.bound.width, height: 100))
footer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
tableView.tableFooterView = footer
```

Comment: this is the better answer. but you don't need to set UIScreen.main.bound.width as width. 0 is sufficient. It will be stretched for the tableView's width.

Comment: This does make more sense because I need the footer only at the bottom of the table view. I tried to go down this road but got stuck. Apple's documentation says "To make the table view aware of your header or footer view, you need to register it. You do this using the register(_:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:) or register(_:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:) method of UITableView". I couldn't get past the error "Cannot invoke 'register' with an argument list of type '(UITableViewHeaderFooterView, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: String)'"

Comment: This is what gave me that error: `let footer = UITableViewHeaderFooterView(reuseIdentifier: "footer")` and `tableView.register(footer, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "footer")`

Comment: you don't register an object, but a class `tableView.register(UITableViewHeaderFooterView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "footer")`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that, @vikingosegundo. I made that change and now see in the console that "Setting the background color on UITableViewHeaderFooterView has been deprecated. Please set a custom UIView with your desired background color to the backgroundView property instead". So, I'll try this and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The @tarasChernyshenko answer is correct, but i think that you need something more specific to obtain the same result as the image that you uploaded.

For this you can set an UIView with zero's frame to the tableView footer, and then set a proper background color to your view.

Something like this:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
view.backgroundColor = .groupTableViewBackground
```

Take advise that the sections header color change from background, it's a normal looked situation, but if you want the same color, only you need to set clear background color to yours header sections. If you don't set a custom view for Headers sections you only need override this function and important, set to clear the background view's background color.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if let view = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        view.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}
```

Positioning footer view by storyboard, you need to put a view with frame zero at the bottom and then set to this a resizing mask pinning and resizing in all sides. The background color of this, doesn't matter cause never be shown.

As data, the background color of header sections by default is `UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.920532 0.920532 0.926863 1`, but it could be change with model or OS.